# How to understanding LeakSanitizer warning in my personal main function without leetcode OJ?

Tags: c

in leetcode problems [67. Add Binary](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-binary/). I use c to solve it.
There is a confused trouble to interface the code.

```c
#include <string.h>
char* addBinary(char* a, char* b)
{
    if(a[0] == '0' && b[0] == '0')
        return a;

    size_t len_a = strlen(a), len_b = strlen(b);
    size_t n = len_a >= len_b ? len_a : len_b;
    int flag = -1;
    char* num1;
    char* num2;
    char* res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (n + 2)); // not sizeof()*n + 2
    res[n] = '\0'; // 0..n

    if(len_a > len_b){
        flag = 0;
        num1 = a;
    }
    else if(len_a < len_b){
        flag = 1;
        num1 = b;
    } else {
        num1 = a;
        num2 = b;
    }
    int i;
    if(flag == 0 || flag == 1){
        num2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (n + 2));
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            num2[i] = '0';
        num2[i] = '\0';
    }
    //
    if(flag == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < len_b ; i++){
            num2[n - len_b + i] = b[i];
        }
    } else if(flag == 1){
        for(i = 0; i < len_a; i++){
            num2[n - len_a + i] = a[i];
        }
    }

    int remainder = 0, j;
    for(i = n -1 ; i >= 0; i--){
        j = (num1[i] - '0' + num2[i] - '0' + remainder) % 2;
        res[i] = j + '0';
        remainder = (num1[i] - '0' + num2[i] - '0' + remainder) / 2;
    }   
    if (remainder == 1){
        char *ans = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (n + 2));

        for(i = 1;i <= n; i++){
            ans[i] = res[i - 1];
        }
        ans[0] = 1 + '0';
        ans[i] = '\0';
        free(res);
        return ans;
    } else {
            free(num2);
        return res;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *a = "10111", *b = "110010";
    char *c = addBinary(a, b);
    free(c);
}
```

As you can see, the terrible code is mess.Different case can  execute different path in addBinary func and free char *num2(freed by addBinary) or char *res(freed by main). Use main, my goal is to test case by hand,if

```sh
gcc -g -fsanitize=address   leetcode-67.c -o 67
vimerbf@debian:~/test/leetcode$ ./67
```

it will throw:

```sh
==2252==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 8 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fcd3ec9dd28 in malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.3+0xc1d28)
    #1 0x5623d45f7d0b in addBinary /home/vimerbf/test/leetcode/leetcode-67.c:39
    #2 0x5623d45f82a9 in main /home/vimerbf/test/leetcode/leetcode-67.c:99
    #3 0x7fcd3e85d2e0 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x202e0)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 8 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

The line 39 is:

```c
if(flag == 0 || flag == 1){
    char *num2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (n + 2));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        num2[i] = '0';

    num2[i] = '\0';
}
```

I know the num2 must be freed.But why leetcode pass my code above?
Are there some problem in my main function?
Thanks！

Comment: You initial test returns `a` if either `a` or `b` begin with a zero digit.  That doesn't make much sense.  Were you attempting to detect empty strings?  If so, then you need to use `'\0'`, not `'0'`.

Comment: If `remainder == 1` then you never free `num2`.  You need to check all possible paths through your code, making sure you (1) never access or free memory you haven't allocated, (2) you free all allocated memory (except for the returned result).

Comment: Also, in the initial case where you return `a`, you will get an error since the caller expects a newly allocated array.  So you can't do that either.

Comment: Hi, @TomKarzes, thank your explation.Got it at your first commit(string a and b should be checked end with '\0').In the initial case, because len_a < len_b, so flag == 1, *num2 point string a.Consider different case value cause excute path.Maybe:newly allocate num1 and num2 points to a and b separately from position 1 to n.Then newly allocate *res to receive the result sum of num1 and num2(from 1 to 2). And before judge **remainder**, free both num1 and num2.Right?

Comment: the posted code fails to compile!  amongst other things, it is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`  which exposes the `malloc()` and `free()` functions

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  note: other compilers used different options to produce the same output.

Comment: OT: regarding: `char *ans = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (n + 2));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.